# Can't start Byobu?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, byobu

I can type this command byobu on the terminal and Byobu will start but when I click on the Gui icon it starts and closes fast.
What I did before that is enable autolaunch and then disable it I thought I should mention this because of this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/byobu/+bug/996873).
How could I fix this?
I'm on ubnutu 12.04.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should clean out your [byobu](http://byobu.co) configuration directory.  It will be recreated on the next startup.

```
rm -rf ~/.byobu
```

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: First of all, thanks for making byobu!

Unfortunately I'm also running into this problem, but the solution doesn't work for me. The byobu config screen is showing up for a brief moment and then getting closed immediately. The problem persists after I run `rm -rf ~/.byobu`

Answer (score 0):

For someone landing because you are facing the same problem: I my case, there was some hanging byobu processes. You can do:

```
ps aux |grep byobu
# select the process IDs for byobu from the output (the second column from left).
kill -9 <id1> <id2> # Where <id1> and <id2> are place holders for your proceses.
```

Obviously, a reboot of the node also helps, but sometimes rebooting is not an option.